# Azure DevOps - I can't delete a task

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am a project administrator (Delete this node: Allow), but I can't delete a task:

> Failed to delete work item: 201.
> Error Details: We were unable to delete the work item(s), you do not have sufficient permissions to delete...

How can I fix it, and be able to delete anything?

I moved the project administrator rights, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Check this permission on your account:

[image]

and check this document: [Remove, delete, or restore work items in Azure Boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/remove-delete-work-items?view=azure-devops)